# Dynamic UnPivot in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to dynamically unpivot columns to rows using bigquery scripting.
I'm trying to replicate what we have [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-in-bigquery-4eefde28b3be) but using upivot operator.

The table looks like this [image]

and I want to transform it to this.

[image]

I'm using this sql sript but its not giving me the desired output in bigquery. Kindly assist.

```
    DECLARE myunpivot STRING;
SET myunpivot = (
  SELECT CONCAT('("', STRING_AGG(DISTINCT column_name, '", "'), '")'),
From(
SELECT column_name FROM Project_Health.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name ="FY22_Operational_PH_Calc_Summary" 
and column_name not in("Subject")));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM Project_Health.FY22_Operational_PH_Calc_Summary`
)
unpivot
(
  Rating 
  FOR Period in %s
)
""", myunpivot);
```

When this is run I get
[image]

The results I get on the 1st job with 10MB job is

```
("Jan_Baseline_thresholds", "Week_1", "Week_2", "Week_3", "Week_4", "Jan_Avg", "Feb_Baseline_thresholds", "Week_5", "Week_6", "Week_7", "Week_8", "Feb_Avg", "Mar_Baseline_thresholds", "Week_9", "Week_10", "Week_11", "Week_12", "Week_13", "Week_14", "Week_15", "Week_16", "Week_17", "Week_18", "Week_19", "Week_20", "Week_21", "Week_22", "Week_23", "Week_24", "Week_25", "Week_26", "Week_27", "Week_28", "Week_29", "Week_30", "Week_31", "Week_32", "Week_33", "Week_34", "Week_35", "Week_36", "Week_37", "Week_38", "Week_39", "Week_40", "Week_41", "Week_42", "Week_43", "Week_44", "Week_45", "Week_46", "Week_47", "Week_48", "Week_49", "Week_50", "Week_51", "Week_52")
```

While the results I get from the second job is

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM Project_Health.FY22_Operational_PH_Calc_Summary`
)
unpivot
(
  Rating 
  FOR Period in ("Jan_Baseline_thresholds", "Week_1", "Week_2", "Week_3", "Week_4", "Jan_Avg", "Feb_Baseline_thresholds", "Week_5", "Week_6", "Week_7", "Week_8", "Feb_Avg", "Mar_Baseline_thresholds", "Week_9", "Week_10", "Week_11", "Week_12", "Week_13", "Week_14", "Week_15", "Week_16", "Week_17", "Week_18", "Week_19", "Week_20", "Week_21", "Week_22", "Week_23", "Week_24", "Week_25", "Week_26", "Week_27", "Week_28", "Week_29", "Week_30", "Week_31", "Week_32", "Week_33", "Week_34", "Week_35", "Week_36", "Week_37", "Week_38", "Week_39", "Week_40", "Week_41", "Week_42", "Week_43", "Week_44", "Week_45", "Week_46", "Week_47", "Week_48", "Week_49", "Week_50", "Week_51", "Week_52")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the issue was the concat line

```
CONCAT('("', STRING_AGG(DISTINCT column_name, '", "'), '")'),
```

Replaced with

```
CONCAT('(', STRING_AGG( column_name, ','), ')'),
```

Below is the complete Query

```
DECLARE myunpivot STRING;
SET myunpivot = (
  SELECT CONCAT('(', STRING_AGG( column_name, ','), ')'),
From(
SELECT column_name FROM Project_Health.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name ="FY22_Operational_PH_Calc_Summary" 
and column_name not in("Subject")));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM Project_Health.FY22_Operational_PH_Calc_Summary`
)
unpivot
(
  Rating 
  FOR Period in %s
)
""", myunpivot);
```