# How do I count the frequency of items for each column with bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column from a Google Bigquery Table which has certain results (na, pass, warn, and error) based on criteria (c1, c2, c3, ...), for example.

```
 data    c1      c2      c3      ...
------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 data1   pass    na      warn    ...
 data2   pass    na      pass    ...
 data3   error   pass    error   ...
```

Now I want to get a histogram for each column of the input table, and I want to create the summarized table as follows.

```
 criteria   na      pass    warn    error
---------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 c1         0       2       0       1
 c2         2       1       0       0
 c3         0       1       1       1
 ...        ...     ...     ...     ...
```

Actually, there are many criteria, so I want to create the summarized table without enumerating the criteria.
How can I get the output table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot then pivot again to get the table you want as such:

```
input as (
  select "data1" as data, "pass" as c1,"warn" as c2,"na" as c3, "pass" as c4 union all 
  select "data2" as data, "na" as c1,"pass" as c2,"pass" as c3, "error" as c4 union all 
  select "data3" as data, "warn" as c1,"pass" as c2,"na" as c3, "warn" as c4 union all 
  select "data4" as data, "pass" as c1,"error" as c2,"pass" as c3, "error" as c4 union all 
  select "data5" as data, "pass" as c1,"na" as c2,"na" as c3, "error" as c4 union all 
  select "data6" as data, "pass" as c1,"warn" as c2,"na" as c3, "na" as c4 
),

step_unpivot as (
select * from input unpivot(results for criterias in (c1,c2,c3,c4))
)

select *  from step_unpivot pivot(count(data) for results in ('pass', 'warn','na','error'))
```

And since you want dynamic column selection for the unpivot(), you can probably use the answer to this question for that part: [Dynamic UnPivot in Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386894/dynamic-unpivot-in-bigquery)

Edit: Below a version with the dynamic unpivot

```
DECLARE myunpivot STRING;
SET myunpivot = (
  SELECT CONCAT('(', STRING_AGG( column_name, ','), ')'),
From(
SELECT column_name FROM dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name ="unpivot_pivot" 
and column_name not in("data")));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
with
step_unpivot as (
select * from dataset_name.table_name
unpivot(results for criterias in %s)
)

select *  from step_unpivot pivot(count(data) for results in ('pass', 'warn','na','error'))
""", myunpivot);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your sample script partially does what I want to do.
Is there a way to specify unpivot column names by variable?

I can enumerate the column names as follows, but can I use this result?
`SELECT column_name FROM <sample_dateset>.<sample_table>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = <table_name>`

Comment: The link I provided at the end should help you do that. It uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to select the columns you want to unpivot in a variable that is used in a subsequent query. I edited my answer with that part integrated

Comment: Thank you so much. The process performed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider below,

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_keys(input STRING) RETURNS Array<String> 
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_values(input STRING) RETURNS Array<String> 
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT criteria, result
    FROM (SELECT * EXCEPT(data) FROM sample_table) t,
  UNNEST (json_keys(TO_JSON_STRING(t))) criteria WITH OFFSET JOIN
  UNNEST (json_values(TO_JSON_STRING(t))) result WITH OFFSET USING (offset)
) PIVOT (COUNT(result) FOR result IN ('na', 'pass', 'warn', 'error'));

+----------+----+------+------+-------+
| criteria | na | pass | warn | error |
+----------+----+------+------+-------+
| c1       |  0 |    2 |    0 |     1 |
| c2       |  2 |    1 |    0 |     0 |
| c3       |  0 |    1 |    1 |     1 |
+----------+----+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your script, but my table is too big and the script couldn't be done. The problem was solved using pivot and unpivot.

Comment: @shok1122,  thanks for confirming that. obviously it makes sense that if you can get column information from information_schema directly rather than from expensive json manipulation, it will run more efficiently.